# Not able to store a very long string in the Oracle varchar column (4000)

Tags: java, oracle

I have a string with length as 4000 and I am trying to store the same in Oracle DB column with type as VarChar(4000). The issue is that the string in not getting stored properly . This is skipping some of the characters.

Comment: Some characters or at end?

Comment: what is the oracle version you are using

Comment: It's skipping characters the end.

Comment: @jayendrabhatt : Oracle version 11g

Comment: Please add more information to your question: table schema, code for saving the string, string to be saved, exact result of operations, Oracle version etc.

Answer (score 0):

The string was actually an XML that was pretty printed. I trimmed the newlines and reformatted in notepad so that it was in a single line when word-wrapped. The oracle DB was able to store it.

So, I adjusted the length of string accordingly by keeping an eye on the no of characters. This worked for me!!